# Move ng-model to child element within a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have written a directive which simply replaces an element with a set of nested tags. The problem is, I want the ngModel to apply to the first inner element, not the outer , which is where it is placed by default.  How can I force the ng-model to apply to the inner element?

First attempt:

HTML:

```
<nested-elements ng-model="mymodel"></nested-elements>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive("nestedElements",function(){
return{
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope:{
        ngModel:'='
    },
    template: '<div class="outer"><div class="inner1">Something</div><div class="inner2"></div></div>'
});
```

Result:

```
 <div class="outer" ng-model="mymodel"><div class="inner1">Something</div><div class="inner2"></div></div>
```

Not what I wanted. I want the ng-model to apply to the inner1 div.

Attempt 2:

html:

```
<nested-elements model="mymodel"></nested-elements>
```

directive:

```
app.directive("nestedElements",function(){
return{
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope:{
        model:'@'
    },
    template: '<div class="outer"><div class="inner1" ng-model="{{model}}">Something</div><div class="inner2"></div></div>'
});
```

Result:

```
<div class="outer"><div class="inner1" ng-model="{{ model }}">Something</div><div class="inner2"></div></div>
```

This is also obviously not what I wanted.

how can I make the ng-model apply to inner1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try attempt 2 with these changes:

```
scope:{
    model:'=ngModel'
}
```

and

```
<div class="outer"><div class="inner" ng-model="model">...
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7zBnC/1/